# Portable relative URLs - folder to domain root

Tags: html, url

I want to write URL that work regardless whether the base URL is either of:

> http://example.com/myfolder/
>
> http://example.com/

E.g.

```
<a href="other.html">Other</a>
```

Should go to

> http://example.com/myfolder/other.html
>
> http://example.com/other.html

respectively,

But instead in both cases they go to:

> http://example.com/other.html

This is not a problem if the base URLs are

> http://example.com/myfolder/index.html
>
> http://example.com/index.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative URIs are always resolved from the base URI which is the URI of the document if not explicitly declared otherwise (see the `base` element). So what is the base URI in your case?

Comment: Yes, there was an errant <base> tag in there that I hadn't noticed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you were testing this with a base url of:

http://example.com/myfolder

(no trailing slash)

If there is no slash, the browser will think "myfolder" is just a file and not a folder.  So click a relative url will not go into that folder.

http://example.com/myfolder/

If the base url is this, then it should work as you expect.

Usually, I prefer absolute URLs just to avoid these headaches.  Just about every link in my webapps is in the style:

/myfolder/other.html

Which always points to the same place from any location.

Comment: Good call. Though those aren't technically ‘absolute URLs’, which would include the full http:... prefix, but rooted relative URLs. Rooted URLs are almost always the most convenient way to do links as long as you know your app will be mounted at a particular place from the root.

Answer (score 1):

If you give exactly like

```
<a href="other.html">Other</a>
```

it is a relative address and it should work like that.

Remember that when you are linking to a file:

```
www.example.com/folder/other.html
```

from:

```
www.example.com/index.html
```

you must give the link in index.html as:

```
<a href="folder/other.html">Other</a>
```

That is, you have to link to the file using the relative address.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in static HTML?  "../other.html" might be a safe bet (assuming you dont get any more nested).